# Add custom block to admin sale order grid

Tags: magento-1.9, layout, order-grid

i am trying to add the custom block after the sale order grid.i tried below xml code but could not succeeded.

```
<adminhtml_sales_order_grid>
    <reference name="sales_order.grid">
        <block type="core/template" name="testing" before="-" template="test/test.phtml"></block> 
    </reference>
</adminhtml_sales_order_grid>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this :

```
<adminhtml_sales_order_index>
   <reference name="content">
      <block type="core/template" name="testing" before="-" template="test/test.phtml"></block> 
   </reference>
</adminhtml_sales_order_index>
```

Answer (score 1):

1 Create a module config file into app/etc/modules/Stackoverflow_CustomSales.xml

```
<config>
    <modules>
        <Stackoverflow_CustomSales>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
        </Stackoverflow_CustomSales>
    </modules>
</config>
```

2 Create a config file under app/code/local/Stackoverflow/CustomSales/etc/config.xml

```
  <config>
        <modules>
            <Stackoverflow_CustomSales>
                <version>1.7.0.2</version>
            </Stackoverflow_CustomSales>
        </modules>
        <adminhtml>
            <layout>
                <updates>
                    <customsales>
                        <file>stackoverflow_customsales.xml</file>
                    </customsales>
                </updates>
            </layout>
        </adminhtml>
        <global>
            <blocks>
                <customsales>
                    <class>Stackoverflow_CustomSales_Block</class>
                </customsales>
            </blocks>
        </global>
    </config>
```

3 Create a block app/code/local/Exercise/CustomSales/Block/Sales/Order/View/Custom.php

```
class Stackoverflow_CustomSales_Block_Sales_Order_View_Custom extends Mage_Core_Block_Template
{

}
```

4 Create a layout config file app/design/adminhtml/default/default/layout/exercise_customsales.xml

```
<layout version="0.1.0">
    <adminhtml_sales_order_view>
        <reference name="order_items">
            <action method="setTemplate"><template>customsales/sales/order/view/items.phtml</template></action>
            <block type="customsales/sales_order_view_custom" name="customsales_sales_order_view_custom" template="customsales/sales/order/view/custom.phtml"/>
        </reference>
    </adminhtml_sales_order_view>
</layout>
```

4 Copy sales/order/view/items.phtml into customsales/sales/order/view/items.phtml
Open this file and add one line code, look like,

```
<div class="grid np">
......
......
</div>
<br />
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('customsales_sales_order_view_custom');?>
```

5 Create a new file customsales/sales/order/view/custom.phtml, you can add your custom content. Clear cache and go to order view page.

Comment: i want to add with sale_order_grid not with sale_order_view